# React using setState within useEffect() problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

N.B. I got my answer here but it is not the duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) thread

I am trying to fetch data from a reusable function that has an API. Here is my code

**usaData.js** in another page

```js
const useData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const fetchData = async (url, query, variable) => {
    const queryResult = await axios.post(url, {
      query: query,
      variables: variable,
    });
    setData(queryResult.data.data);
  };
  
  return {data, fetchData}
};
```

I am retrieving data from this **MainPage.js** file

```js
export const MainPage = props => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        pharam: 'Yes',
        value: '',
    });

    const [field, setField] = useState([])

    const {data, fetchData} = useData()

    const onClick = (event) => {
        setState({ ...state, pharam: '', value: event });

        fetchData(url, query, event)
        setField(data)
    }

    return (
        <div>
          ...
          <Select
              placeholder='select'
          >
              {field.map(item => (
                  <Select.Option key={item.name}>
                      {item.name}
                  </Select.Option>
              ))}
          </Select>
          <Button onClick={onClick}>Change Select</Button>
          ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem is `setField(data)` within `onClick` function is not updating immediately as it is a async call. Hence I tried to use a function as a second argument

```js
    ...
    setField(data, () => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    ...
```

It is returning the following warning in red color but the behavior is similar to earlier, not updating data immediately.

> Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

As per the warning then I tried to use `useEffect()` within the `onClick` function

```js
...
    const onClick = (event) => {
        setState({ ...state, pharam: '', value: event });

        useEffect(() => {
          fetchData(url, query, event)
          setField(data)
        }, [data])
    }
...
```

which is returning an error

> React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "onClick" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"

Where do I have to make changes? How can I get expected behavior as the `setField` will update the `field` immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not setState in your custom hook rather than return promise.

**usaData.js**

```
const useData = () => {
  const fetchData = async (url, query, variable) => {
    return await axios.post(url, {
      query: query,
      variables: variable,
    });
  };

  return { fetchData };
};
```

**In MainPage.js**

Now when you trigger your **onClick** function just call your fetchData function with await or then syntax and after successfully api call you'll  get back the result in the newData variable which you can use it to update your state.

Note: this will save you an extra useEffect.

```
 export const MainPage = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    pharam: "Yes",
    value: "",
  });

  const [field, setField] = useState([]);

  const { fetchData } = useData();

  const onClick = async (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, pharam: "", value: event });

    let newData = await fetchData(url, query, event);
    console.log("===>", newData.data.data);
    setField(newData.data.data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <Select placeholder="select">
        {field.map((item) => (
          <Select.Option key={item.name}>{item.name}</Select.Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <Button onClick={onClick}>Change Select</Button>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is that `setField` gets calls before your data is fetched.

So, you can have a `useEffect` which gets executed every time the `data` gets changed.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(data.length > 0) {
    setField(data);
  }
}, [data])


const onClick = (event) => {
        setState(prev => ({ ...prev, pharam: '', value: event }));
        fetchData(url, query, event);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to use `fetchData()` in multiple click such as `anotherClick()` event and update `anotherField` by `setAnotherField()`. Then every click will affect the `useeffect` and it will update only the `setField` data.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, React sets its state asynchronously. So, in order to update the state Field, you need an useEffect hook. Your approch with useEffect is correct, except it neeed to be placed outside onClick (directly in the component function).

```js
export const MainPage = () => {
...
    useEffect(() => {
        setField(data)
    },[data])
...
}
```

Comment: but I need to call it after triggering `onClick` function

Comment: @Devil'sDream it should update everytime the state `data` changes including when you click the button.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to use `fetchData()` in multiple click such as `anotherClick()` event and update `anotherField` by `setAnotherField()`. Then every click will affect the `useeffect` and it will update only the `setField` data.

Comment: @Devil'sDream how about using multiple `useData` hook? or maybe create a `fetchData` function which return the data  instead of using state for storing the data.